# Mismatched links for Jira internal and external url

Tags: url, jira

I have a different URL for internal and external users. However, when I click on some of the links in the internal URL it redirects me to the external URL, is there anyway to ensure all links in the internal URL links to the internal URL and not the external URL? (e.g. clicking the logo in the banner links me to the external URL but other links on the dashboard links me to the correct URL)

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue with ClearQuest in the past, and we ended up with the simplest solution - having internal users required to use the external URL.

Comment: You're right. Some links in Jira are absolute, they're builded with the "public URL" (see "system configuration"), and you can only configure 1 public URL. So, there is no other way : everyone shall use the public URL

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if it is possible to fix the problem this way in your case, but  probably the error comes from general configuration of jira instance: make sure that in admin>system>general> URL Base attribute is correct. If you manage two Jira instances, you just have to sest it correctly on both.

I got the same problem with the test instance. And was weird to find that!!

Good luck